# How do I bound a number between two constants using the modulus operator?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def boundThis(x):
    min = 20
    max= 100
    boundX = int(x)
    if (boundX > max):
        boundX = boundX % max + min-1
        if (boundX > max):
          boundX-=max-1
    else:
        while(boundX < min):
            boundX += max-min
    return boundX
```

I'm trying to bound x between two numbers, 20 and 100 (exclusive). That said, once it hits 100, it should loop back to 20.

I get how it works with the while loop, (while boundX < min) but am having trouble with the *modulus* operator and writing the correct expression with that.

Ex. boundThis(201) should give me like 21, and boundThis(100) giving me 20.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit a number to be within a specified range? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996881/how-to-limit-a-number-to-be-within-a-specified-range-python)

Comment: Although actually looking at this closer.... Are you trying to have the number wrap around, rather than clamp? I.E. `min = 10, max = 15` and `number = 9, output = 15`, `number = 16, output = 10`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do note that `min` and `max` are already builtin functions, so don't name variables with those identifiers as you can't do something like the following (assuming you are not trying to generate a list of numbers within the specified bounds):

```
>>> def bound(low, high, value):
...     return max(low, min(high, value))
... 
>>> bound(20, 100, 1000)
100
>>> bound(20, 100, 10)
20
>>> bound(20, 100, 60)
60
```

Edit:

For the wrap around condition, think of this as a math problem.  As you know the modulus operator essentially finds the remainder of what is left over from a division operation on a divisor, so we can use that.  So the base case is very simple if you have an offset of `0` to `n`.

```
>>> 99 % 100
99
>>> 101 % 100
1
```

But you want it offset from some base value (`low`), so you have to apply basic mathematics and reduce that problem to the one above.  I would suggest you try to figure this out on your own before reading the solution below.

```
>>> def bound(value, low=20, high=100):
...     diff = high - low
...     return (((value - low) % diff) + low)
...
>>> bound(0)
80
>>> bound(19)
99
>>> bound(20)
20
>>> bound(100)
20
>>> bound(99)
99
```

Comment: Even if you're trying to generate a list it would work fine, you'd just use a list comprehension like `list = [bound(20, 100, value) for value in numbers]`