# set time limitations for timer

Tags: python, time

Is there are nicer way to write the code like this?

```
# ugly piece of code
seconds = 0 if seconds < 0 else seconds
seconds = 86399 if seconds >= 86400 else seconds
```

I mean - I need to setup the strict possible range of seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit a number to be within a specified range? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996881/how-to-limit-a-number-to-be-within-a-specified-range-python)

Comment: `divmod(seconds,86399)[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seconds = max(0, min(86399, seconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def check(start, end, sec):
    return end if sec > end else start if sec < start else sec
```