# Python make a number loop within a range

Tags: python

So I saw this post, [on limiting numbers,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5996881/6759115) but I noticed it would cut a number off if it wasn't within the range.

Is there a way to do this like so:

`variable = 25`

If your range is 1-20, can `variable` become 5?

Or if `variable = 41`, have it become 1?

I have tried this:

```
 def loop(number, maxn, minn):
     if number > maxn:
         number = maxn - number
     return number
```

With a range of 0-20, and a number of 40, I got -20?!?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the problem. What have you tried? Are you trying to set a valid for a number and if it's off the range, then set it to 1?

Comment: The term is _modulo operation_. I'm sure you can find a solution yourself, now that you know how this operation is called.

Comment: @dmlittle If a number is greater than the range, I would like it to loop back from start, thus, if the input is 5 greater than the max of the range, it should be 5 greater than the min of the range.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Provide a algorithm (not code, but the way you think) why `41` gives us `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.

```
def loop(n, minn, maxn):

    while n > maxn:
        n = n - (maxn - minn)
    while n < minn:
        n = n + (maxn - minn)

    return n
```

I think that should work for most cases, including negative numbers and ranges.

Comment: You can skip the `if`s. The `while`s will take care of the check automatically since they're using the same conditional.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks, I forgot about that.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla `loop(49, 38, 40)` returns 47 which is more than max.

Comment: @VPfB Whoa. Just tried that. It's probably because 49 - 40 is < 38. If you keep minn at 1 or 0, it works fine.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla and I don't know what result would be correct and why. 38? 39? Or 40? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla You could also try `loop(49,-1,0)`. It will never stop.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla `(minn + maxn)` is incorrect and should be the same as the first one as you're trying to get a range to add or subtract.

Comment: @Ouroborus Oh, yeah.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla You've still got them backwards. `maxn - minn` doesn't produce the same results as `minn - maxn`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set `variable = (|variable| % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN`. This will give you a number that is between `MIN` and `MAX`, inclusively.

Note that this only works consistently if `variable`, `MAX` and `MIN` are non-negative integers, and `MAX >= MIN >= 0`.

The reasoning behind this is as follows: `|variable| % (MAX - MIN + 1)` is necessarily non-negative, given that `MAX - MIN + 1` and `|variable|` are non-negative, and so the modulos must be non-negative. Thus the lowest it can be is zero. We add `MIN` after, so the number at its lowest in total can be `MIN`.

At most, `|variable| % (MAX - MIN + 1)` is `MAX - MIN`, due again to the nature of the modulos operator. Adding `MIN` afterwards gives us `MAX`. Thus the highest output will be `MAX`.

No `variable` will give a number that is lower than `MIN` or higher than `MAX`, and there is always an equal number of `variable` such that `n = (|variable| % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN`, for all `n` between `MIN` and `MAX` inclusively.

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this should work. Will it work if MIN and MAX are negative?

Comment: This still doesn't seem to make it start over at the beginning though...