# Return 0.0 and 1.0 if input falls below 0.0 or above 1.0

Tags: python, if-statement, floating-point, idioms

The goal is to "do something" if the input value falls between (0.0, 1.0).

Otherwise,

- return 1.0 if input is >= 1.0 or
- return 0.0 if input is <= 0.0

The straightforward way would be to:

```
def func(x):
    if x >= 1.0:
        return 1.0
    elif x <= 0.0:
        return 0.0
    else: 
        return do_something(x)
```

But it's also better to use some max/min trick like this:

```
def func(x):
    if 0 < x < 1.0:
        return do_something(x)
    else:
        return max(min(x, 1.0), 0.0)
```

**Which coding style more Pythonic returning clipped values if it falls below 0 and above 1 and if otherwise, the float needs to be manipulated?**

`do_something()` is some float manipulation that should return a value between (0.0, 1.0), i.e. exclusive of 0.0 and 1.0.

For simplicity, treat it as:

```
def do_something(x):
    return x**2
```

---

To further explain the question, the (0.0, 1.0) range excludes the 0.0 and 1.0, i.e.

```
>>> x = 0.231
>>> 0 < x < 1.0
True
```

So if `0 < x < 1.0`, the desired output has to be put through the `do_something()` function that returns a value (0.0, 1.0), e.g.

```
>>> x**2
0.053361000000000006
>>> 0 < x**2 < 1.0
True
```

I guess the confusion in the comments comes when you're asking why don't I just `do_something()` first then "clamp"/"clip" the outputs, i.e:

```
>>> x = 0.231
>>> max(min(x**2, 1.0), 0.0)
0.053361000000000006
```

But let's say you have a negative no. as an input:

```
>>> x = -0.231
```

**The desired output is 0.0**. But if we do just simply `do_something()` first then "clamp"/"clip", we get the wrong output:

```
>>> x = - 0.231
>>> max(min(x**2, 1.0), 0.0)
0.053361000000000006
```

---

Perhaps square is a little too simplified to describe `do_something()`.

The actual function looks more like this:

```
def do_something(x):
    ratio_y, score_y = 1.5, 0.5
    beta = math.log(score_y) / math.log(score_y)**2
    return math.exp(beta * math.log(x)**2)'
```

Due to the asymptote nature of logarithms, the checks for (0.0, 1.0) needs to be explicit before calling the `do_something()` function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return do_something(x)`?

Comment: Second one, obviously

Comment: Also, why don't you let `do_somthing` decide? the code will be cleaner this way.

Comment: @DeepSpace Then he'd just have the same question about the code in `do_something`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit a number to be within a specified range? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996881/how-to-limit-a-number-to-be-within-a-specified-range-python)

Comment: for your information, this operation is often called "clamping"

Comment: @HakenLid this question is a little different because, there's the "else" part that needs to "square" the input if it's within (0.0, 1.0)

Comment: @NickChapman This isn't clamping, because the conditional is on the input, not the result.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a common enough idiom that there's likely to be a preferred pythonic way. Just write whatever you feel is clearest.

Comment: No, it's not clamping. If the input is not more than 1.0 or less than 0.0, it needs to be squared!!

Comment: but when you square a result between 1 and 0, the result stays between 1 and 0, so in this case, clamping on the input or the result has same effect.

Comment: I see. I guess it's not a duplicate. OTOH questions about best practice tend to be off topic, since it's more or less a matter of subjective preference. Also, is it something you would like to use several times, you could make it into a higher order function / decorator, and apply it with something like `@clamp_conditional_func(max_bound, min_bound)`, for instance.

Comment: Yes, but if input above 1.0, it's easy to detect but if it's under 0, then the square will make it within the (0.0, 1.0) range, which is the undesired output.

Comment: @NickChapman does the updated question explains the question better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the decorator style if you like.

The decorator (with custom min and max values):

```
def limit_decorator(min_val, max_val):
    def inner_decorator(func):
        def wrapping_func(x):
            if x >= max_val:
                return max_val
            elif x <= min_val:
                return min_val
            else:
                return func(x)
        return wrapping_func
    return inner_decorator
```

you can use it like this:

```
@limit_decorator(0.0, 1.0)
def do_something(value):
    return value**2
```

alternatively, use can you a simple decorator (with predefined limits):

```
def limit_decorator(func):
    def wrapping_func(x):
        if x >= 1.0:
            return 1.0
        elif x <= 0.0:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return func(x)
    return wrapping_func
```

which you can you like:

```
@limit_decorator
def do_something(value):
    return value**2
```

Comment: Why obscure simple logic by hiding it in a decorator?

Comment: @Sneftel it's not obscuring the logic if you are going to use this method all the time. If you're just doing it a single time then I agree that using the decorator is more annoying than just putting the logic in the function. But if you were going to repeat this 10 times with different functions then a decorator is a good way to deal with this.

Comment: @Sneftel He asked for a code style, not for a solution. I believe it can be useful in some cases. If it's being used once that i agree that there are shorter ways.