# A simpler way to check multiple variables against a certain parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming that I have three variables `r, g, b`. If any of these variables are `< 0` or `> 255`, they are to be rounded to `0` and `255` respectively.

My unsophisticated knowledge of python would tell me to utilise a bunch of **if-statements**, which  I think would be time-consuming and unnecessary. **Is there any other method of doing this?**

Comment: On second thought, I could perhaps use a for-loop, but I await answers.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996881/how-to-limit-a-number-to-be-within-a-specified-range-python

Comment: How about `r = max(0,min(r,255))` etc? That does coercion into the range 0..255 as part of the test, and avoids the `if` statements you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

```
if 255 > variable > 0:
```

You can simplify mathematical parameters somewhat like this.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, does this really solve my purpose considering I will still have to ascertain whether the variable was ```> 255``` or ```< 0```, to round it to the appropriate figure?

Answer (score 1):

```
rgb = (0,255,125)
check = [(0<=value<=255) for value in rgb]
print(sum(check)==3)
# -> True
```

This checks for whether all values fits the critera.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `numpy`, and you have an array of your values you can clamp your values with a single line of code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ ... values ...])
a[a > 255] = 255
a[a < 0 ] = 0
```

`numpy` has optimizations for operations on vectors, so for large amount of values `numpy` might be also faster.

Answer (score -1):

```
if r in range(0, 255):
    # code
```

You could see if you like this syntax

Comment: Note that this only works if `r` is an integer.