# Mapping a Matrix onto a Coordinate Plane

Tags: python, math, algebra

I am researching how to map a matrix onto a coordinate plane. For example, let's consider a 4x4 matrix. I want this matrix to be mapped onto the coordinate plane with points ranging from -2 to +2 on the x-axis and -2 to +2 on the y-axis. The center of the matrix should always be at the point (0,0). Therefore, the point (-1.5,1.7) should correspond to the matrix[0][0] point. Is there a technique for achieving this?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand your goal. Are you trying to approximate coordinates using the matrix? Or are you trying to perform some transformation to real-world coordinate systems (e.g. WGS84)?

Comment: i updated question with image

Comment: So you're looking to get a formula to convert x / y coordinates into i / j matrix indices?

Comment: Yes, but the center of the matrix should always be at the point (0,0)

Comment: since Y-axis increases in opposite direction as the corresponding matrix index the formulas are different for x and y. - I thoughts I saw a comment of yours with the correct idea in X.

Comment: Isn't it just add 2 to the grid coord and round down? If you need to invert the relationship, invert the grid coord first as in `math.floor(-gridY)+2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 4x4 case if you have the point at coordinates **x,y**:

```
i = math.trunc(2+x)
j = math.trunc(2-y)
value = m[j,i]
```

**value** will will your matrix value at x,y coordinates. For the more general case, if your matrix has size (height, width) the code is:

```
i = math.trunc( width/2 + x )
j = math.trunc( height/2 - y )
value = m[j,i]
```

This will make a mess if the x, y coordinates are out of bounds so you might need:

```
if i<0: i=0
if i>= width: i=width-1
if j<0: j=0
if j>= height: j=height-1
```

before `value = m[j,i]`.

See [How to limit a number to be within a specified range? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996881/how-to-limit-a-number-to-be-within-a-specified-range-python) for a better suggestion how to do that.